# How to pop items from a collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

Is there a method in JDK or apache commons to "pop" a list of elements from a java.util.List? I mean, remove the list of elements and return it, like this method:

```
public Collection pop(Collection elementsToPop, Collection elements) {

  Collection popped = new ArrayList();

  for (Object object : elementsToPop) {
    if (elements.contains(object)) {
      elements.remove(object);
      popped.add(object);
    }
  }

  return popped;
}
```

Comment: Do note that you can test the result of remove() and skip the contains check in your code.

Comment: You may also want to look into [generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for working with collections.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're looking for a stack-like structure I suggest accepting a `Deque` (`LinkedList` is the most common implementation) instead of a `Collection`.

If you don't actually need to treat it as a stack, just get an iterator from the `Collection` and use the `remove()` method:

```
for (Iterator<SomeType> it = elements.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    SomeType e = it.next();
    it.remove();
    popped.add(e);
}
```

Do note that remove is an optional operation, and some implementations may throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` (for example, the iterator returned by a Collection from `Collections.unmodifiable...()` will).

**Edit**: After looking more closely at your question, I think you just need this:

```
elements.removeAll(elementsToRemove);
```

If your main point is you need to know exactly *which* elements were actually popped, I think you're stuck with your original code.

Comment: Actually, it appears I didn't read closely enough.  You have a very non-standard definition of "pop" that mislead me to post this answer.  More applicable answer coming.

Comment: I know "pop" was not the best word to use, so I gave an example of what I wanted. But looks like there's no method like this implemented for JDK or apache commons, so, by now, will continue with my own, and I will use your Iterator hint, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method in the standard JDK-provided methods.  Apache Commons provides [the `ListUtils.subtract()` method](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#subtract(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)).

Edit: As other answerers have noted, your use of the term `pop` is nonstandard.  Usually,

> The pop operation removes an item from the top of [a stack]

Wikipedia has a [nice description of stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29).

Comment: +1 for subtract; removeAll doesn't respect cardinality like the poster's snippet does.  But this doesn't get you a list of elements that were actually removed like his does.

Comment: @Mark, hm, you're right; I read the description but not the source, and misunderstood.  +1, I will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

I guess no, because you definition of 'pop' operation is highly non-standard. Usually it takes no arguments (except collection itself) and returns and removes the top-most one.

But once you noted apache commons, this would achieve the same effect as your code.

```
Collection result = CollectionUtils.intersection(a, b);
a.removeAll(b);
```

**edit**
http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Linked List provides the functionality as you require, provides a push and pop method.

Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) as provided:

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a method exactly like what you are asking for, but it looks like you are already pretty close with your code.

Some suggestions:

- Consider using removeAll(object) instead of remove(object) if elements is an arbitrary collection since you may need to remove duplicates e.g. if elements is a list.
- contains() is slow for some collection types (e.g. lists) since it needs to traverse the entire data structure. Given that this is in your inner loop you are at risk of O(n^2) performance issues. If you can make the algorithm work with a HashSet or HashMap then contains() will by O(1) and your algorithm will be much more efficient.