# How to remove and return an object from a Hashset?

Tags: java, hashset, bluej

I have a Hashset that has been populated with Penny objects and I want to create a method to remove one of these Penny objects from the HashSet and return it. Here is the method I have created to do this but it does not work as I get error messages. can someone explain to me the correct way of doing this

```
public Penny removePenny(){

    if(penniesSet.size()<= 0){
        return null;
    }
    else 
        penniesSet.remove(Penny)

    return penniesSet.get(Penny)
}
```

Comment: What types of error messages?

Comment: I assume you already put missing `;` in your actual code but you forgot to put in above

Comment: `penniesSet.remove(Penny)` <--- do you know the difference between an object and a class?  Also where is the code that populates the set?  And assuming the set has a dozen objects in it, how do you think the code above selects which one of those dozen to remove?

Comment: This isn't compilable for multiple reasons. I suggest you get started with a book first, Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a book, tutorial or class.

Answer (score 2):

`penniesSet.remove(Penny)` and `penniesSet.get(Penny)` will not work, as `Penny` is class name, not a value. If you want to get any element from the set to remove, use `set.iterator().next()`:

```
public Penny removePenny() {

    if (penniesSet.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    Penny penny = penniesSet.iterator().next();
    penniesSet.remove(penny);
    return penny;
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, `remove()` returns a `boolean`. For a correct implementation see my answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Oops, was thinking of `remove` on `Map`.

Comment: Did you just copy-paste my own answer, without even giving credit?! Amazing.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Don't be so keen to attack others... I mistakenly used `remove`, and in fact used the `Iterator` concept before you updated.

Comment: "Copy-paste" - absolutely not factual. Look at the casting on your answer.

Comment: I can confirm that August was using the iterator concept when on my screen Oscar's post still had the `penniesSet.remove(Penny)` line (see my comments on his post).  I am not sure what "fact" was being pointed out, since all I see is an accusation veiled as a question, but the "fact" that accusation implies is nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a Type `Penny` to the `remove` method.  You should be passing an object.

As for the `get` method you should probably read this:
[Why doesn't java.util.HashSet have a get(Object o) method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863506/why-doesnt-java-util-hashset-have-a-getobject-o-method)

Furthermore, a typical issue that can cause problems looking up an object in a `Hashset` is if `Penny` doesn't have a proper [hashCode](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/hash_function_guidelines.shtml)() method.

Removing an arbitrary `Penny` like this might not be exactly what you were trying to do in the first place.  If, you want to remove the last one added (called popping from the stack) you may want to look into using a [different collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998848/how-to-pop-items-from-a-collection-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make use of Iterator to return and remove the penny object from Hashset. 
Try following code:

```
public Penny removePenny(){
    Penny p = null;
    Iterator it = penniesSet.iterator();
    if(it.hasNext()) {
        p = (Penny) it.next();
        it.remove();
    }
    return p;
}
```